# Curl with GSS-API on Alpine Docker

Tags: docker, curl, kerberos, alpine-linux

I am trying to get curl installed in a Dockerfile with the `GSS-API`, `SPNEGO`, or `GSS-Negotiate` features installed so I can use the `--negotiate` flag.  How can I configure curl to be installed with that feature or how can I compile curl with that feature in my Dockerfile?

I have searched a lot and can't find any answers.

Currently, `curl --version` gives me this:

```
/ # curl --version
curl 7.77.0 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/7.77.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 nghttp2/1.43.0
Release-Date: 2021-05-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

After running:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql
RUN apk add krb5
RUN apk add rsync
RUN apk add --update libgss
RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh sshpass
RUN apk add --upgrade --no-cache curl
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `apk add --update --no-cache krb5 krb5-dev` is enough for `GSS-API`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).